Getting a true or false return from database if a username already exists
I am making a small project that uses a database, when user is creating an account, I need to check the database if the username is available.
My code is something like this:
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="user",
    password="password",
    database = "users"

mycursor = db.cursor()


username = input("Username: ")

mycursor.execute("SELECT username FROM users")

for x in mycursor:
    if x == username:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)

I saw some similar questions to this, but they either aren't with Python, they aren't working for me or I just don't understand them.

Your code has a syntax error in it. A bracket was never closed.

import mysql.connector
    
# Connect to the database
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "user",
    password = "password",
    database = "users",
)

mycursor = db.cursor()
username = input("Username: ")

# Use SELECT and WHERE to check if it already exists
query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = %s"
mycursor.execute(query, (username,))

# Fetch one result
result = mycursor.fetchone()

# Check if the result is None or not
if result:
    print(True)  # Username exists
else:
    print(False)  # Username does not exist

mycursor.close()
db.close()


This can differ in an important way from the code in the question.  This (assuming a typical-for-mysql case insensitive column) will look for e.g Fred or FRED if given fred.
